# rm -rf with missing w permissions on directories without root or chmod

Tags: permissions, directory, rm, recursive

I'm trying to recursively delete a directory with `rm -rf`, but this fails because some inner directories don't have the `w` permission set. I know how to fix this with `chmod`. However, this requires to iterate over the whole directory twice, which can be slow.
Is there a way to remove such a directory in one go? (Assuming you have enough permissions to give yourself enough permissions)
`sudo` is not an option (limited user on pc in question).

Comment: what's wrong with `chmod -R 0777 <dir> && rm -rf <dir>`

Comment: same but slower `find <dir> -depth \( -exec chmod 0777 {} + -a -exec rm -r {} + \)`

Comment: That it has to go over the whole directory twice (once for `chmod -R` and once for `rm -r`, which seems unnecessarily slow). I'm looking for `rm -rf` but adjust permissions on the fly if necessary

Comment: you can use find `-perm` flag to only chmod necessary files but i doubt that there is any faster way than chmod -R

Comment: Using `-perm` will not give you the possibility to remove whatever you find, and thus will require to go over everything once more. I'll setup some test

Comment: dont you think *chmod -R* is smart enough? at least, it has a verbosity flag which is telling you which files changed and which retained. of course, if you know for sure *rm -rf* will not fail on files but only on subdirs *-type d* may useful

Comment: `find` does not work. Suppose `maindir/subdir1/subdir2/file` with no `w` on `subdir1` and `subdir2`. Without `-depth` it crashes on `subdir2` when `rm -rf`'ing `subdir1` as `file` is not deleted because no `w` of `subdir1`. With `-depth` it crashes on removing `rm -rf`'ing `subdir2` as `w` on `subdir1` is missing.

Comment: reason must be missing `r-x` find works fine with `-depth` https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgcIL.png

Comment: Indeed, upon recheck, with `+` it works, while it fails with `\;` (what I was doing out of bad habit). This suggests `+` might also fail when reaching the maximum command length. Whether that is something worth worrying about will depend on the complexity of the directory structure.

Comment: No,  `find`, like  `xargs` batches calls to the command to limit the size fo the arguments.

Comment: To my understanding, that is why it might fail. It works with `+` and not with `\;` because all necessary `chmod` is done before `rm`. That might not be true when splitting in batches. Using `{}/*` instead of `{}` like the spirit of your answer below fixes this issue with `subdir1/subdir2` though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rsync` with an empty dummy directory seems fine:
`mkdir empty; rsync -r --delete empty/ targetdir/; rmdir empty targetdir`
With a 10x repeated test on a simple example, this took 10-14s (14 was an outlier, all others took 10 or 11s),
vs. `chmod -R u+w targetdir && rm -rf targetdir`, which took 19-25s
and `find targetdir -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; && rm -rf targetdir`, which took  12-16s but will likely deteriorate more than rsync with more complex folder structures.

Comment: this should be accepted answer because it's **exactly** what asked and the only one that **doesn't** `chmod` (besides the fact that every `find` construct will badly fail on missing read permissions)

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
find directory -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
rm -rf directory
```

Comment: Is this not iterating over the whole directory tree twice as well?

Comment: +1 for `-type d` because it makes it faster as it is not unnecessarily changing permissions on files. You do not need permissions on a file to delete it, this is managed by the `w` permission of the directory it is in.

Answer (score 1):

I did not do performance measurements. I just guess it makes sense to delete all the files immediately when a directory is read (because it is read completely anyway and you might risk losing already read metadata from the page cache with `-depth`) and change the permissions of those 1st level subdirectories then for which that is necessary. With lots of files and subdirectories it seems hard to avoid reading the same directory content again and without the files that should be much faster.

I suggest to use a wrapper script which is called for each directory. That script makes `find`

- delete all files in the argument directory
- fix the permissions of level-1 subdirectories where necessary
- call the script for each level-1 subdirectory

```
#!/bin/bash
  
set -x

dir_path="$1"

test -d "$dir_path" || exit 1

declare -i tests_x=0
declare -i tests_x_limit=30
while true; do
    # there is a race condition between the -exec + and xargs
    if [ -x "$dir_path" ]; then
        break
    else
        sleep 1
    fi
    tests_x+=1
    if [ "$tests_x" -gt "$tests_x_limit" ]; then
        exit 1
    fi
done

find "$dir_path" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -delete -o -type l -delete \
-o -\( -type d ! -perm -700 -exec  chmod u=rwx {} + , -print0 \) |
    xargs -0 -n 1 -r "$0"
```

And run this with

```
deletion.sh /start/dir
```

You need `rm -r` afterwards as the above approach does not delete the directories (and cannot do so in a useful (i.e. faster than `rm -r`) way IMHO).

Independently of the command approach it may help to increase the filesystem commit time. So for `ext4`:

```
mount -o remount,commit=60 /path/to/mp
```

Comment: I like this answer because it follows the question's spirit of not reading directories twice. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to delete the directory tree itself (also after adding `-` to `type` in `-o` and adding `-o type l` after `-type f`

Comment: @KoenG. Right, I forgot to mention that you need `rm -r` afterwards. It seems to me that it is impossible to do this with just one directory read. So it is just about minimizing the pain. You can reduce it to reading **large** directories just once (assuming most of the entries are files) once with my solution so that `rm -r` is fast. My solution could be improved by writing the directory paths to a FIFO and have some background process read them from there and read those directories every few seconds in order to keep their metadata in the page cache so that the `rm -r` is as fast as it can be

Comment: Changing to `\;` i.o. `+` for the `chmod` and adding `rmdir "$dir_path` at the end deletes the directories on the fly. As far as I can see all directory contents are only read once in that case (by the `find`). Very disappointed that this kind of behaviour is not an option of `rm`, but an approach like this is what I was looking for. Unfortunately, it is very slow in my testing. This might be the overhead of bash scripting though (and lack of parallellism). I'll set up a test on a slower drive to shift the balance (this will take some days due to practicalities).

Comment: Calling `rmdir` for just one directory is not very efficient, though. I also just realize that my approach keeps one instance of `bash` and `xargs` running for every directory. This whole thing should rather be done in Python, Perl or whatever so that you do not have the overhead of new processes.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a small shell in each directory to change its mode and delete its contents:

```
find . -depth -type d -exec sh -c 'echo "Removing $1 contents"; chmod +w "$1" ; rm -r "$1"/*' anything {} \;
```

Comment: That is a terrible idea because pathname expansion results are sorted. Exactly the problem that is to be avoided.

Comment: Using `$1/*` instead of just `$1` does fix the problem with `find` and `subdir1/subdir2` with `w` missing on both `subdir1` and `subdir2` (it never tries to remove any folder's content without setting its `w` permission first). Using multiple `-exec` instead of `-exec sh -c` (because it was faster), this took 18-20s on the test case of the [rsync answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/599752/375116)